# React Navigation from Component with expo

Tags: components, undefined, react-navigation, expo, react-props

I am trying to use React Navigation from inside another component which is primarily getting called from a screen.
Hierarchy: The login screen has a button component that has a TouchableOpacity component designed and that login button is supposed to call another screen, Home.

login.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import CupertinoButtonSuccess from "../components/CupertinoButtonSuccess";
import CupertinoButtonWarning1 from "../components/CupertinoButtonWarning1";
import MaterialIconTextbox from "../components/MaterialIconTextbox";

//function Login(props) {
  export default class Login extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
      headerShown: false
    };

    render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.coMproTech1}>COMproTECH</Text>
      <View style={styles.rectStack}>
        <View style={styles.rect}>
          <CupertinoButtonSuccess
            Navigation={this.props.navigation}
            text1="Login"
            style={styles.cupertinoButtonSuccess}
          ></CupertinoButtonSuccess>
          <CupertinoButtonWarning1
            text1="Forgot Password"
            style={styles.cupertinoButtonWarning1}
          ></CupertinoButtonWarning1>
          <Button  title='test' onPress={this.handleClick}></Button>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.rect2}></View>
        <MaterialIconTextbox
          textInput1="Enter email"
          icon1Name="account"
          style={styles.materialIconTextbox}
        ></MaterialIconTextbox>
        <MaterialIconTextbox
          icon1Name="account-key"
          textInput1="Password"
          style={styles.materialIconTextbox2}
        ></MaterialIconTextbox>
      </View>
      <Text style={styles.services1}>Services</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(74,144,226,1)"
  },
  coMproTech1: {
    color: "rgba(247,242,242,1)",
    fontSize: 36,
    fontFamily: "Cochin-BoldItalic",
    marginTop: 110,
    marginLeft: 16
  },
  rect: {
    top: 19,
    left: 0,
    width: 342,
    height: 319,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    position: "absolute",
    borderRadius: 20,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 20
  },
  cupertinoButtonSuccess: {
    width: 65,
    height: 39,
    borderRadius: 6,
    marginTop: 200,
    marginLeft: 261
  },
  cupertinoButtonWarning1: {
    width: 167,
    height: 44,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 9,
    marginLeft: 159
  },
  rect2: {
    top: 0,
    left: 48,
    width: 42,
    height: 42,
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,255,255,1)",
    position: "absolute",
    transform: [
      {
        rotate: "45.00deg"
      }
    ],
    borderRadius: 7
  },
  materialIconTextbox: {
    top: 59,
    left: 0,
    width: 343,
    height: 48,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  materialIconTextbox2: {
    top: 141,
    left: 0,
    width: 343,
    height: 48,
    position: "absolute"
  },
  rectStack: {
    width: 343,
    height: 338,
    marginTop: 125,
    marginLeft: 16
  },
  services1: {
    color: "rgba(247,242,242,1)",
    fontSize: 36,
    fontFamily: "Cochin-BoldItalic",
    marginTop: -450,
    marginLeft: 18
  }
});

//export default Login;
```

CupertinoSuccess.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, Button } from "react-native";
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';
import { NavigationInjectedProps } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";


function CupertinoButtonSuccess(props) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}
    style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
      <Text style={styles.caption}>{props.text1 || "Button"}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#4CD964",
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    paddingRight: 12,
    paddingLeft: 12,
    borderRadius: 5
  },
  caption: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 17,
    //fontFamily: "Cochin-BoldItalic"
  }
});

export default CupertinoButtonSuccess;
```

Getting error/exception:

```
undefined object 'this.props'

TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props')

createReactClass$argument_0.touchableHandlePress
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\TouchableOpacity.js:264:45
touchableHandlePress
    [native code]:0
TouchableMixin._performSideEffectsForTransition
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:880:34
_performSideEffectsForTransition
    [native code]:0
TouchableMixin._receiveSignal
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:779:44
_receiveSignal
    [native code]:0
TouchableMixin.touchableHandleResponderRelease
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Components\Touchable\Touchable.js:490:24
touchableHandleResponderRelease
    [native code]:0
invokeGuardedCallbackImpl
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:307:15
invokeGuardedCallback
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:531:36
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:555:30
executeDispatch
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:722:42
executeDispatchesInOrder
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:744:20
executeDispatchesAndRelease
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:907:29
forEach
    [native code]:0
forEachAccumulated
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:887:16
runEventsInBatch
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:932:21
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:1096:19
batchedUpdates$argument_0
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2796:6
batchedUpdates$1
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18791:14
batchedUpdates
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2709:30
batchedUpdates$argument_0
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2794:17
receiveTouches
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:2870:28
__callFunction
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47
__guard$argument_0
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26
__guard
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10
__guard$argument_0
    D:\Android Projects\React_Projects\SplashNav\snav\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
    [native code]:0
```

Comment: Hi Sir, Updated with error log.

Answer (score 0):

You have a function component with the `props` argument:

```js
function CupertinoButtonSuccess(props) {
  // ...
}
```

Inside, you're using `this.props.navigation.goBack()`. But `this.props` is not available in function components. You need to change it to use `props.navigation.goBack()` (without `this`).

Comment: Hi Sir, I am new to react native, can you please help me with this cause I tried without 'this.' but did not work, also, how can I change
function CupertinoButtonSuccess(props)
to
class CupertinoButton cause when I am trying, it says undefined props.

Comment: You should read official React docs and make yourself familiar with React if you are new to React Native

Answer (score 0):

There are things you need to know about react navigation and especially the stack navigation that you're using. The current version is navigation 5.

> It allows you to navigate between screens which are components passed
>   down to the react navigation's file, let call that configuration file
>   App.js.  In your case, your screens are "Home" and "Login", which
>   means that you should have the Home.js and Login.js components or
>   functions set somewhere in your projet.

//This is the minimum configuration you should have for App.js
// Watch out, the '@' is very important for navigation 5

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';

const Stack  = createStackNavigator();

export default class App extends React.Component {

 render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName='Home'>
           <Stack.Screen name='Home'    component={Home} />
           <Stack.Screen name='Login' }  component={Login} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Your Login.js component is just like you did, but you should pass the navigation props to CupertinoButtonSuccess and CupertinoButtonWarnings, otherwise they can't automatically access the navigation props because you have not defined them as sceens in the navigation configuration file. To do that you just have this in the render method of Login.js

```
render(){ 
  return(
 <CupertinoButtonSuccess navigation={navigation} /> 
 <CupertinoButtonWarning1 navigation={navigation} /> 
);
}
```

instead of

```
render(){
return(
<CupertinoButtonSuccess Navigation={this.props.navigation}
           ... > </CupertinoButtonSuccess>
<cupertinoButtonWarning1 Navigation={this.props.navigation}
           ... >
</cupertinoButtonWarning1> 
);
}
```

(You even never close a custom component like that in react native. Only the build-in react native components such us View, Text have closing Tags like 
`"<View></View>"` or `"<Text></Text>",` 
but here  is a custom component because it belongs to you alone and not to all react native developpers. Additionaaly you imported "CupertinoButtonWarning1" with begining capital letter "C" and now calling it as "cupertinoButtonWarning1" was another mistake, but I hope that was just typing errors.

Now about how to make CupertinoButtonSuccess class component instead of function based component, you will need to create two class based components, one for CupertinoButtonSuccess.js and the second cupertinoButtonWarning1.js because you can't render two class based components from the same single component.

// So for CupertinoButtonSuccess.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, Button } from "react-native";
//You never need to be calling { createStackNavigator } here again because //CupertinoButtonSuccess.js is not a screen
 export default class CupertinoButtonSuccess extends Component {
   render(){
       return (
    <TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack('Home')}
    style={[styles.container, props.style]}>
      <Text style={styles.caption}>{props.text1 || "Button"}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   //Your style here
});
```

//For CupertinoButtonWarning1.js you do same.

Finally and for the sake of completness, there is another way to use navigation props straight in the CupertinoButtonSuccess.js and CupertinoButtonWarning1 themselves, without waiting for Loging.js to pass it to them, it's by importing "useNavigation" like this in CupertinoButtonSuccess.js and CupertinoButtonWarning1.js :

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
```

This way you have access to the navigation props even from CupertinoButtonSuccess.js and CupertinoButtonWarning1.js.
The documentation about this is here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/